# Last (failed) logins - or - why elevated permissions for btmp

Tags: debian, login

Why do I need to have elevated permissions to access the last failed logins (`/var/log/btmp`) but not for the last successfull logins (`/var/log/wtmp`). (At least per default on debian/ubuntu linux - my system: debian 9)

Are there any security considerations?

Basically I would like to run `lastb` on every login and thus set read permission for all users `chmod o+r /var/log/btmp`. Any contradictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read access to that log is a way for (local) attackers to access account passwords in cleartext, because (according to the OpenSSH people) the most common failure mode for login is when the user accidentally types the password at the prompt for the account name.

## Further reading

- Ashok (2005-01-20). *[Record Badlogins for all supported Authentication methods](http://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=974)*. OpenSSH bug #974.
- Darren Tucker (2005-02-02). *[Teach `sshd` to write failed login records to `btmp`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/2fba993080eba14e339d6a6666ee79580ee20f97)*.  OpenSSH.  GitHub.
- dean gaudet (2005-06-19). *[Excess permission or bad ownership on file `/var/log/btmp`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=314956)*. Debian bug #314956.
- Ken Bowley (2005-12-03). *[openssh-server: doesn't log bad login attempts to `/var/log/btmp`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=341883)*. Debian bug #341883.
- Mark Charter (2017-08-03). *[systemd: `/var/log/btmp` has inconsistent permissions](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870638)*. Debian bug #870638.
- Franck Bui (2017-10-04). *[Why does tmpfiles want the "utmp" group for `/var/log/btmp`?](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6994)*.  systemd bug #6994.  GitHub.

Comment: "failure mode for login is when the user accidentally types the password" so obvious, I didn't think about it. Thanks for the links!